# Tools/plugins to help display an online course

Tags: google-slides

I have a question in regards on which recommended tools to use to display a presentation. Here ate the details:

We are wanting to sell our online course through Amazon Marketplace. The idea is when the user clicks to purchase the course, they are sent an email with a link. Now currently our presentation is in google slides but we cannot share google slides with them because one may risk edit, two it's not the best UI for self study course.

What we was hoping was placing our course in an interface that has the following split screen and lesson selection capabilities:
- Slides on one side
- Text notes on the other side with scroll
- Able to select lessons from a menu

So when the user selects the link, it will take them to that interface to view. Does anybody know any tools or plugins that support this?

Comment: Would it be sufficient for your purpose to share you slides in presentation mode?